# Installing QGIS (client, not server) on RHEL 8

Tags: qgis-3, linux, red-hat

I'm having trouble getting a recent QGIS version installed on RHEL 8 ('8.5 (Ootpa)'). It's not available in any of the standard repositories. I've found some resources on how to go about it on RHEL 7, but that won't work on RHEL 8.

I did find that installing `mini-conda` allows an individual user to install a recent and working version of QGIS on their own profile, but I don't like getting every user to install this sizeable piece of software in their own home directory. It does however show that there are recent builds of QGIS that work well on RHEL 8.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to install a recent QGIS on RHEL 8? Or perhaps on a resource that would show how to install QGIS through mini-conda in a way that would make it useable by all users?

Comment: I don't use RHEL, but workaround could be to install a system-wide miniconda and QGIS env and create a .desktop file that activates the QGIS env and runs QGIS. https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/admin-multi-user-install.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up following @user2856's suggestion, and installed miniconda system wide, set up an environment and installed QGIS in that, to allow all users to be able to start it:

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
su
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -bfp /miniconda
/miniconda/condabin/conda update -n base -c defaults conda
/miniconda/condabin/conda init bash
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
conda create --name qgis_env
conda activate qgis_env
conda install qgis matplotlib numpy -c conda-forge
exit
```

Note: I installed matplotlib and numpy because they were requirements for plugins I need

After all this, other users can also run `/miniconda/envs/qgis_env/bin/qgis`. I use X11 so I have that set up as well:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install xorg-x11-xauth xorg-x11-apps
export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
xclock
```

This should run the `xclock` app on your local GUI, assuming `X11 forwarding` was set to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. If `xclock` starts, so should QGIS.